# How to select node from potentially not well-formed xml as a varchar?

Tags: sql, xml, xml-parsing, nvarchar

I have varying 'message' columns which is a varchar that should be an xml, but some of them may not be well-formed or valid. I am trying to weed out the rows that have a given input value to a node like this:
Select * from messagelog where message like '%1234567%'

But when I filter those to try and lift another node (1234567) whos value I do not know, I come across the issue.

I've casting every entry to a xml wont work since like 1% of messages are not valid.

This code doesn't parse the varchar into xml, but returns a substring if it exists. However, I get a conversion error on the charindex = 0 case. Some MessageIds are these large varchars.

Is there anything that I'm missing here? Am I SOL for using SQL to parse not well-formed XML varchars?

```
select
case when CAST(charindex('<RelatesToMessageID>', message) as varchar(100)) = 0
then 1
else
substring(message, charindex('<RelatesToMessageID>', message)+20,     charindex('</RelatesToMessageID>', message)-charindex('<RelatesToMessageID>', message)-20)
end
from messagelog

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '959B91D824324108948261EC2A81CD92' to data type int.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CASE` is returning both a `VARCHAR` and an `INT`. You should change your  `then 1` to `then '1'` so both parts of your `CASE` return a `VARCHAR`

Answer (score 1):

I saw that I could select the substring only in locations where there are an existing NCPDPID. This would get rid of the case altogether.

```
if exists(Select * from messagelog where message like '%<NCPDPID>1234567</NCPDPID>%')

select substring(message, charindex('<MessageID>', message)+11, charindex('</MessageID>', message)-charindex('<MessageID>', message)-11) from messagelog where message like '%<NCPDPID>1234567</NCPDPID>%'
```